# How to integrate AWS API Gateway API Key with Axios | CORS Error

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, postman, aws-api-gateway, api-key

I have built an `API` in `AWS API Gateway`. I have written the endpoints to perform basic CRUD operations as well. I am making a call to those endpoints using `axios` from my `React frontend`. The APIs in turn call `AWS Lambda functions` to interact with `DynamoDB`.

Since `DynamoDB` contains sensitive user data, I wish to secure it with an API key.

As per the steps mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html).

Now in order to make an API call I had the following code. Please note that I have swapped in the real values with dummy values for explanation purposes.

**src/config/api.js**

```
const customHeaders = {
  "X-Api-Key": "thisIsADummyStringForExplanation",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://this.is.a.dummy.base.url/v0",
  headers: customHeaders,
});

const Aws_Api_Gateway_GET = (uri) => {
  return axiosInstance({
    method: "get",
    url: `${uri}`,
    timeout: 2000,
  });
};

export { Aws_Api_Gateway_GET };
```

Following is the Code that I wrote in order to make a `GET` request at the API endpoint

```
Aws_Api_Gateway_GET("/my-resource")
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

**THE ISSUE**

This code throws `CORS Error`. I can assure that I have enabled CORS on the API Gateway by selecting the `Enable CORS option` for each and every resource.

[image]

Following is the error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://this.is.a.dummy.base.url/v0/my-resource' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

But when I try the same using `Postman`, it works.

[image]

**Can someone please help me get rid of the CORS Error ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same error here and same situation !

Comment: Have you deployed the API (Actions -> Deploy API)? I just ran into this after adding a new endpoint!

Comment: @mkst yes, i have

Comment: @TanishqVyas - Do you recall solution for this issue? I am having same issue. I have API gateway which works fine without x-api-key. When  I enable X-Api-Key it does work with Postman but not with axios call?

Comment: @Gayatri The issue hasn't been resolved yet